# Can I customize my keyboard input method

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a laptop with Turkish Keyboard. However, I am not used to its layout. If I set keyboard layout to TRQ Keyboard I will misplace the position of `:` and `;` and many others. If I set it to US Keyboard I will misplace the position of `(` and `)` and others.

Photo of the keyboard:
[image]
Can I make a new customize layout that works fine for me? I mean to set for example `(` and `)` from TRQ and `:` and `;` from USQ.

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean keyboard mapping?

If so, use your favourite search engine for `keyboard mapping`. Many of them can be affected by various configuration settings.

Alternatvely, only show `(` when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> (regardless of language chosen)

`AutoHotKey` seems to be a favourite